# How to add accept function in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkfTL.jpg)

Want function that if we click accept we cannot edit , use visual studio and asp.net core mvc ,
With details: if I click accept, the (edit and accept) button will be hidden

How to write function to make this

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question you asked is a typical 'gimme-the-codez' kind of question and will likely be closed very soon. People will happily help with particular issues but not write code for you. Please take the time and read the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe define a value in your database for this user who want to edit and then after he edits and save changes then make that value true and when this razor page is loaded , query the value from the table, check and hide the button accordingly

Comment: You could use javascript to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create property "accepted" for each student, then use condition to decide if render the buttons or not. You could try the below steps for test.
1.create a MVC project.
2.create a model StudentSchedule.cs

```
    public class StudentSchedule
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public DateTime ScheduleDate { get; set; }
        public bool Accepted { get; set; }
    }
```

3.Add scaffold controller
[image]
[image]

4.update the efcore database by "add-migration" and "update-database"

5.In the generated controller "LabrequestsController.cs" Add Accept function.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Accept(int? id)
        {
            var studentSchedule = await _context.StudentSchedule
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            studentSchedule.Accepted=true;
            _context.Update(studentSchedule);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return View("Index", await _context.StudentSchedule.ToListAsync());
        }
```

6.Modify the views/labrequests/index.cs file as below.

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication120.Models.StudentSchedule>   //the model path

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ScheduleDate)
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ScheduleDate)
            </td>

                @if (item.Accepted == false)
                {
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Accept" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Accept</a>
                    </td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td></td>
                }

        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Test
[image]